# Adding a "New Tab" dynamically in the Tab widget in Google App Maker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

Google App Maker allows me to drag and drop the "Tabs Layout" widget on a page and add the required tabs from the "Tab Properties" section using the "NEW TAB" button, but this makes it a static way to do things. 
My requirement here is that I want to add new tabs to the tab layout dynamically using either an array of tab names or from the Data-source.
Somebody please suggest a way to achieve this in Google App Maker.

Comment: Most AM widgets are static elements and therefore do not allow dynamic editing per say. What you can do instead is build your own dynamic 'tabs layout' element by accessing your DOM tree via `document.appendChild()` for example and then looping over each of your datasources and again using document to append all elements that you wish to display within each tab when each datasource loads. I presume most people will not want to spend the amount of time to code this so the other alternative would be to add all the necessary tabs and hide them if they are not needed.

Comment: I faced this two days ago and this is what I found. You can imitate a tabs look by making a grid table that outputs only a button with the string (from a lookup table datasource) and making it wide.

Comment: Ultimately I did a single column table with just the buttons rather than the grid, because that made things too wide). And then I changed parameters for the datasources when the tab button was clicked.